# Dropdown submenu goes back to initial position

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a dropdown submenu and it works out fine mostly, but the problem is that the moment I try to go down with my cursor on it, the submenu goes down to the original position.

I've tried several solutions, like an :after pseudoclass, z-index on the list, heck I even tried to give a negative value so that the submenu goes over the element that needs to be hovered, still nothing.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

```
<div class="settings">
      <div class="settings__language">
        <div class="settings__language__primary"><img src="../scss/vendors/img/uk_icon.jpg" alt="" class="settings__language__flag">
          <span class="settings__language__text">United Kingdom</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-angle-down settings__language__icon"></i></div>
      <ul class="settings__language__list">
        <li class="settings__language__item current">English</li>
        <li class="settings__language__item">Romana</li>
        <li class="settings__language__item">Deutsch</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
.settings__language {
  &__primary {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  &__text {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.7;
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  &__flag {
    width: 1.8rem;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
  }

  &__icon {
    color: $color-primary;
  }

  &__list {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 8rem;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba($color-black, 0.2);
    transform: translateY(1rem);
    // visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  &__item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.4rem 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:nth-last-child(1) {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    &:nth-last-child(3) {
      margin-top: 1rem;
    }
  }

  &__primary:hover + &__list {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `transform: translateY(1rem);` from `.settings__language__list` prevents the menu from moving

```css
.settings__language__primary {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.settings__language__text {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.settings__language__flag {
  width: 1.8rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

.settings__language__icon {
  color: $color-primary;
}

.settings__language__list {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 8rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba($color-black, 0.2);
  /* transform: translateY(1rem); */
  /* visibility: hidden; */
  transition: all 0.2s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.settings__language__item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.4rem 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.settings__language__item:nth-last-child(1) {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.settings__language__item:nth-last-child(3) {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}


.settings__language__primary:hover+.settings__language__list {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="settings">
  <div class="settings__language">
    <div class="settings__language__primary"><img src="../scss/vendors/img/uk_icon.jpg" alt="" class="settings__language__flag">
      <span class="settings__language__text">United Kingdom</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-angle-down settings__language__icon"></i></div>
    <ul class="settings__language__list">
      <li class="settings__language__item current">English</li>
      <li class="settings__language__item">Romana</li>
      <li class="settings__language__item">Deutsch</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do apologize, I wasn't accurate in my question. The effect that I am looking for is for the sub menu to appear and  go up when I hover over the div and stay in that position when I put my cursor over it, but I've even tried to just use position absolute and moving it with top, but still doesn't work. I gave top a negative value so it goes over the div but it still doesn't work

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. So the submenu should only appear when you hover over United Kingdom? And then disappear when your mouse moves off of it?

Comment: Yeah sorry for that, that part was working alright, the problem was I couldn't hover the sub menu as well because I didn't include the sub menu inside the hovered element in html

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It was silly, in the html the sub menu had to be inside the element used for the hover effect.